# Fibd points where target can be increased

Tags: machine-learning

I have to solve the following problem. The data and numeric target is given. Target represents the efficiency of mobile stations and data consists of technical and usage characteristics. The task is to find stations which work inefficient, so target for them can be increase and predict that increase. And additional task is to find reasons why the station works inefficient, e.g. highlight features which cause low efficieny. I wonder are there common approaches for a task like that? It is neither regression nor classification, since there is no true target, is not outlier detection since the data allegedly is consistent. Also what is the right way to formulate such problem for searching solutions?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you're trying to accomplish beyond predicting efficiency. Can you post some of the data, say the top rows of your dataset and what they represent? It sounds like a linear regression based on your description, but again, not clear if I'm understanding correctly.